# Adding custom shadow in AppBarLayout under TabLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-styles, android-appbarlayout

I've added a custom shadow below my `TabLayout` in `AppBarLayout`, but for some reason, there's a green background underneath the shadow:

[image]

In case that's not clear enough, here it is again with a longer shadow:

[image]

As you can see, there's a green background underneath the shadow and I'm not sure how to get rid of it.

Then I noticed, in the Design tab, that the `AppBarLayout`'s background was set to green (even though it's not set to any color in the layout's XML):

[image]

I tried changing the color to `@android:color/transparent`, but it made the background (behind the shadow like in the above pictures) white, and not transparent. So I'm still not sure what's going on.

Here's my layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tablayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:tabBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TabTextAppearance"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/colorTabText" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/toolbar_shadow" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is `toolbar_shadow.xml` drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <gradient
        android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:endColor="@color/shadowColor"
        android:angle="90" />

</shape>
```

And here is the color (20% opacity):

```
<color name="shadowColor">#33423f3f</color>
```

What am I doing that's wrong?

Comment: AppBarLayout has default background `?colorPrimary`. Clear it by `android:background="@null"`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AppBarLayout has default background `?colorPrimary`. Clear it by setting `android:background="@null"`.

Which brings us to the question you're going to ask tomorrow:

> Why content does not draw underneath my custom shadow?

To which I say use the power of `CoordinatorLayout` and put the shadow outside of the `AppBarLayout`.

#### styles.xml

```
<style name="Widget.Shadow.AppBar" parent="">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/toolbar_shadow</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">4dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="layout_anchorGravity">bottom</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">bottom</item>
</style>
```

#### layout.xml

```
<CoordinatorLayout>
    <AppBarLayout android:id="@+id/appbar">
        <Toolbar/>
        <TabLayout/>
    </AppBarLayout>
    <ViewPager/>
    <View 
        style="@style/Widget.Shadow.AppBar"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"/>
</CoordinatorLayout>
```

Put the custom shadow view at the end so it draws over the content underneath.

Explanation: By using this code you declare that you want the shadow view to

- draw below (`android:layout_gravity="bottom"`)
- the bottom edge (`app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"`)
- of the App Bar (`app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"`)

Comment: Just one more question. What about scroll flags? How do I make the shadow disappear when the user scrolls down?

Comment: Set an [`AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener.html). I haven't used this one so you may have to experiment to find out how exactly it works.

Comment: `android:background="@null"` didn't work, used `elevation="0dp"` instead

Comment: @RafaelMuhamedzyanov Yes, AppbarLayout casts shadow *on Lollipop+* even with null background. I was, perhaps wrongly, assuming the custom shadow was used only on Android 4. A "correct" fix would be to call `appbarLayout.setOutlineProvider(ViewOutlineProvider.BACKGROUND);` at run time.